# How to map Java Thread to OS Thread on Linux？

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, jvmti, async-profiler

I'm trying to map Java Thread to OS thread within [JVMTI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jvmti.html). In JVMTI, all I could grab is Java Thread object leveraging [GetCurrentThread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jvmti.html#GetCurrentThread). But I want to know which OS thread this jthread is mapping to.

I was told that there is a field in Hotspot, **eetop**, which is a pointer to the underlying OS-level native thread instance of the JVM(ref: `hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp`).

How do I use this field to finish the mapping?

This magic is also being performed in [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) at `src/vmStructs.cpp line 364`. Why it works?
[image]

Comment: If your JVMTI agent subscribes to `ThreadStart` event, you can create your own jthread->os_thread_id mapping in `ThreadStart` handler.

Comment: @apangin I think I've understood the code in async-profiler about `initThreadBridge`. Thank you.